# Regular Expression javascript repeat with optional sections

Tags: javascript, regex, find-occurrences

Why doesn't this javascript regexp code work? According to the documentation it should:

Here's my String for parsing (it's the rails nested form information):

```
flex_table[flex_rows_attributes][0][flex_cells_attributes][0][id]
```

What I want are these sections, which may or may not be part of the string:

```
flex_rows_attributes, 0, flex_cells_attributes, 0
```

Here's my regular expression(as I mentioned, the javascript flavour):

```
flex_table((\[(\w+)\]\[(\d+)\])*)
```

I only get back the last of the two entries, but I want them both.

Does anyone know, what I am missing here?

Comment: When you repeat a capturing group, only the last capture is kept. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!flex_table\b).*$|(\[(\w+)\]\[(\d+)\])
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ9xT1/26

Comment: Wow, it's really working. It humbles me that my own efforts didn't even come close to any kind of solution path and yours looks so elegant. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is killing me, but how would I need to change the expression to also grab the string in the space for flex_table?

Comment: @LongHike what d testt string